# Printing a value from a user input

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like so,

```
replies = {'0':'Leave it out to dry for 24 hours, if it does not work see customer service',
           '1':'Go to a repair store to get it fixed',
           '2':'Charge the phone battery',
           '3':'Try resetting the phone',
           '4':'Check to see if something blocking the audio jack or the speakers',
           }
```

I have `int(input(,` and I want the user to input a number to print out the value from the dictionary, I tried `print(replies[number the user input])`

But it doesn't work, any help is appreciated, also not I am not very experienced, so simplicity helps, thanks

Comment: print(replies[str(number the user input)])

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the number (integer) as key you need to have your data like this:

```
replies = {0: 'Leave it out to dry for 24 hours, if it does not work see customer service',
           1: 'Go to a repair store to get it fixed',
           2: 'Charge the phone battery',
           3: 'Try resetting the phone',
           4: 'Check to see if something blocking the audio jack or the speakers',
           }
```

In this case, it say maybe better to use a list and accessing your data by the index.

Answer (score 0):

```
replies = {'0':'Leave it out to dry for 24 hours, if it does not work see customer service',  
               '1':'Go to a repair store to get it fixed',  
               '2':'Charge the phone battery',  
               '3':'Try resetting the phone',  
               '4':'Check to see if something blocking the audio jack or the speakers',
               }
```

your indexes are not integers, that's why you can say print replies[1]

just change your dictionary to

```
replies = {0:'Leave it out to dry for 24 hours, if it does not work see customer service',
           1:'Go to a repair store to get it fixed',
           2:'Charge the phone battery',
           3:'Try resetting the phone',
           4:'Check to see if something blocking the audio jack or the speakers',
           }
```

Comment: your indexes are not integers, that's why you can't say print replies[1]*

Answer (score 0):

This one is working.... try this..

```
 input1=raw_input("Enter number ")
 print replies[input1]
```

You are trying to convert input key to integer.... but replies dictionary keys are in string....